CSV download for formated csv file from json in Salesforce LWC
I have a json with multiple nodes and formatted incoming json response from a service call. It is formatted in apex to display multiple tables as desired. From json structured to have different tables in csv. During download action encountering error as Error generating CSV Error: Lightning Web Security: Unsupported MIME type. I need to resolve this error to complete download action.
handlerDownloadCSV(csvContentFromJSON) {
try {
const csvData = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(csvContentFromJSON)));
const blob = new Blob(\[csvData\], { type: 'text/csv' });
if ('download' in document.createElement('a')) {
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
a.download = 'data.csv';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
} else {
const csvUrl = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + csvData;
window.open(csvUrl, '\_blank');
}
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error generating CSV', error);
}
}

Need to resolve Error generating CSV Error: Lightning Web Security: Unsupported MIME type.
